# What does [Inexact] in the console mean when running qmake?

Tags: qt, logging, qt5, qmake

In my **Qt5** project I have the following log statement in a **.pri** file that is included multiple times in a for-in-loop by my main **.pro** file (Qt5 qmake):

```
message("== INC: $$lo)")
```

For most values of `$$lo` it print the following (expected) string:

> Project MESSAGE: == INC: myValue)

But for some cases, a `[Inexact]` is prepended so that it instead looks like this:

> [Inexact] Project MESSAGE: == INC: myValue)

What does that mean? Should I care? How could I get rid of it (it's kind of annoying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: The `[Inexact]` prefix is added by Qt Creator IDE, and is of no consequence as to the correctness of the `.pro` files.

It doesn't mean that there's anything wrong with your project file, but merely that Qt Creator can't figure out where this message originated. It means that it could come from a file other than the one indicated/assumed. It seems to be there to prevent you from going off on a wild goose chase on a message that doesn't really originate in the `.pro` file you think.

See [`ProMessageHandler::ProMessageHandler`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/b1f1ccb32ec31a1c4598e9fd22b23c1548a73299/src/plugins/qtsupport/profilereader.cpp#L44).